# Date format issue php

Tags: php, mysql

Let me show you my code:

```
$from = implode(" ",$_POST['from']);
$date_from = str_replace('/', '-', $from);
$l->from_start=date("Y-m-d",  strtotime($date_from));
```

The problem is that I am getting zeros in my db. It is very strange because when I echo the value from_start I get 2016-06-10 which I believe it is in the right format.

The db field type is `DATE`.

The database is receiving data but apparently with the new plugin something is wrong regarding the date format

Could someone give a hint or something because I am truly lost.

the PDO to insert the data into the DB is the following:

```
$query = 'INSERT INTO student_education (student_id,studies,school,from_start,to_end) VALUES (:a,:b,:c,:d,:e)';


    $studies= $this->studies;
    $school= $this->institution;
    $from_start=$this->from_start;
    $to_end=$this->to_end;

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

$loop = count($studies);    

for($j = 0; $j < $loop; $j++) {
$studies_s = $studies[$j];
$school_s = $school[$j];
$from_s = $from_start[$j];
$to_s = $to_end[$j];

$stmt->bindValue(':a', $studentid) ;
$stmt->bindValue(':b', $studies_s);
$stmt->bindValue(':c', $school_s);
$stmt->bindValue(':d', $from_s);
$stmt->bindValue(':e', $to_s);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

As I said,data is getting inserted but for the date fields nothing happened. I don't see any errors in my PDO code :S

Comment: Y-m-d is the correct format.  I think the str_replace may be unnecessary, string to time will recognize m/d/Y, if you have 2016-06-10 for that then the problem is likely elsewhere.  You should check the actual sql being used to insert the record.

Answer (score 0):

mysql date format is `yyyy-mm-dd`

Not sure what you're doing with the `str_replace` but this should work:

`$requestDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['from']));`

Comment: that is sorta what they already have ( - the unnecessary string replace ), see `I echo the value from_start I get 2016-06-10`, it's likely the issue is further on down toward where they are inserting the record.

Answer (score 0):

`It is very strange because when I echo the value from_start I get 2016-06-10`. Since you get the correct Date, then the code that generates the MySQL-formatted Date for you is pretty much OK. However, it may be logical to assume that the Problem may lie beyond the code that you posted here. Somewhere after the line: `$l->from_start = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_from));` It is advised to either post your Insert Logic (SQL) or revisit your code:

```
    <?php
        // FROM WHAT YOU SAID... THE 3 LINES OF CODE BELOW ARE "GREEN"
        $from            = implode(" ",$_POST['from']);  //CONVERT DATE ARRAY TO STRING
        $date_from       = str_replace('/', '-', $from); // REPLACE SLASHES WITH DASHES
        $l->from_start   = date("Y-m-d",  strtotime($date_from));
```